# How to comparing pageviews stemming from search and from navigation on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to see how many users view products by using the search feature vs how many go through using the nav.  All pages using the search have "/search" in the URL and all pages going thorough the navigation have "/department".  I'm wondering if there is a way to see how many pageviews there are that contain each of those terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Google Analytics on the site, just go to the `Behavior` section and `All pages` report, then you can also use the filter to isolate the pages path you want.